# ImageJ GenericDialog - String containing backslashes is not escaped when recording macro

Tags: java, api, imagej

I am developing an ImageJ plugin and I ran into this problem.

I am using `GenericDialog` with a text field so the user can input a file system path to a file. On windows, the path contains backslashes. When I am recording a macro for this plugin, I get this result:

```
run("Example ", "path=C:\results.txt");
```

The backslash is not escaped and when i try to run the recorded command, the backslash is interpreted as an escape character and obviously, the file can't be found.

Is there a way to use `GenericDialog` in a way that it correctly records text field containing backslashes? Or I can't use `GenericDialog` and have to implement macro recording functionality myself?

EDIT:
example plugin with the problem:

```
import ij.IJ;
import ij.ImagePlus;
import ij.gui.GenericDialog;
import ij.plugin.filter.ExtendedPlugInFilter;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilter;
import ij.plugin.filter.PlugInFilterRunner;
import ij.process.ImageProcessor;

public class Example_ implements ExtendedPlugInFilter {

  public int showDialog(ImagePlus imp, String command, PlugInFilterRunner pfr) {
    GenericDialog gd = new GenericDialog("Example");
    gd.addStringField("path", "C:\\results.txt");
    gd.showDialog();

    String path = gd.getNextString();
    IJ.showMessage("path = " + path);
    return PlugInFilter.DONE;
  }

  public void setNPasses(int nPasses) {
  }

  public int setup(String arg, ImagePlus imp) {
    return PlugInFilter.NO_IMAGE_REQUIRED;
  }

  public void run(ImageProcessor ip) {
  }
}
```

When i run the macro recorded from this plugin, it shows "path = C:esults.txt".

Comment: That's apparently a bug in the macro recorder. Chances are high that this will be fixed quickly if you report this to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html).

Comment: With an up-to-date version of [Fiji](http://fiji.sc/Fiji) (ImageJ 1.47s), the macro recorder records `run("Results... ", "open=C:\\results.txt");` when I run the command _File > Import > Results..._. Did you check if your ImageJ version is up to date? My ImageJ doesn't know the command "Import results", but only "Results...", are you sure you're using the correct command?

Comment: `Import results` in this case is not the built-in command but a plugin i am developing. I will add a SSCCE to the question shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is solved in the latest version of ImageJ (1.47t). In this version, if you record a macro from a `GenericDialog` containing Windows path in a StringField, the recorded value is correctly escaped.